# Polymer Confirmation of page leaving

Tags: javascript, polymer, single-page-application, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

How can we implement this feature in Polymer?

[image: confirmation example]

(example from github wiki page editing)

I suppose we have an application based on the [Polymer Starter Kit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/polymer-starter-kit/index?hl=en) (so with [page.js](https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/) as router engine)

- my application uses a `product-editor` element which contains a textarea + a save button.
- User is editing a product at the route `localhost/#!/product/127/edit`
- He "accidentally" clicks on the Back button or other links on the page

I'd like to display the above confirmation dialog: `"Are you sure to leave..."`

How can we do this?

Comment: You could try hook into the [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) handler and use an element like [`paper-dialog`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog).

Comment: I don't think the window.onbeforeunload will triggered in a SPA

Answer (score 0):

You can use page.exit("/product/:id/edit", function(next){ }); and handle in this callback the action you want to perform: display a popup for user.

Comment: after the page.exit() the page will be redirected anyway, how can I stay on the the current page?